# Blank links opens in the same window - Why, and how to fix it?

Tags: html, hyperlink, cross-browser

I have four links:

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
<a href="http://bing.com" target="_blank">Bing</a>
<a href="http://yahoo.com" target="_blank">Yahoo</a>
<a href="http://wikipedia.com" target="_blank">wiki</a>
```

When I click on a link, it will opens in a new window.
And on click to another link, it will opens in the same window opened last time.

It is not good for me, I want to open a blank window on every single click, regardless of the opened windows.

How can I handle this? (I don't care about double-click Google link opens it twice, doesn't matter.)

And this is works, just it have to.

**EXCUSE ME, communication problem with my PHP beast.**

So, actually the links are like:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick = "window.open('http://google.com','Admin');">gaagle</a>
<a href="javascript:;" onclick = "window.open('http://bing.com','Admin');">bang</a>
<a href="javascript:;" onclick = "window.open('http://yahoo.com','Admin');">yahuu!</a>
```

And now, all the stuffs opens to the same window, because of the name tag (2nd param of window.open) -.- And since all the opened window's ID was Admin, every other windows opened on that window. I did not checked it, excuse me for wasting your time.

Comment: Can't reproduce in FF7, Chrome 15, or IE8 - it always opens a new window. Which browser are you testing in? Are you sure there's no javascript interfering?

Comment: I'm not seeing what you describe at all, you'll have to reproduce the problem somehow.

Comment: Can you reproduce in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YLzCt/1/) the behavior you're experimenting?

Comment: i remember encountering that years ago. just a wildshot: have you configured your browsers to actually open windows or tabs? i have the feeling that it indeed uses the same window, when a link opens in a window.

Comment: Trying :) But it's not so easy, because its fine at me too. Gimme a sec.

Comment: OH GEEEZ my PHP programmer felt like a js haxxor and renewed the template with a kind of magic.... -.- So not, the generated menus like  `<span class="{ACTIVE}"><a href="javascript:;" onclick = "window.open('{LINK}','{NAME}');">{NAME}</a></span>` whick makes the problem's solution easy. But anyway, if we are here... I going to edit the question.

Comment: I ran into similar issue, then found out i had my target property set to '_Blank' with capital B. Editing it to '_blank' solved the issue.

Comment: Was able to reproduce; if you're in javascript adding <a href="#!" onClick={function(e) { ... })}} target='_blank'> seems to correct this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you give each link a different target, they will open in different tabs / windows.

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="googleWindow">Google</a>
<a href="http://bing.com" target="bingWindow">Bing</a>
<a href="http://yahoo.com" target="yahooWindow">Yahoo</a>
<a href="http://wikipedia.com" target="wikiWindow">wiki</a>
```

If you click a second time on a link, it will re-use the existing window if it is still available.

If you use `target="_blank"` every click should be in a new tab / window, regardless of previous clicks. If you aren't getting this behaviour, what browser are you using?

If you want all clicks to goto the same window use...

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="myWindow">Google</a>
<a href="http://bing.com" target="myWindow">Bing</a>
<a href="http://yahoo.com" target="myWindow">Yahoo</a>
<a href="http://wikipedia.com" target="myWindow">wiki</a>
```

Comment: Neet, i did not know this :) But the problem already solved by asking the programmers: Did anybody edited my templates?  `o.  o.  o/  o.`

Comment: You might want to consider this alternative as it doesn't required JavaScript.